# remove local scope for another query eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models. `User` and `Task` which have many-to-many relationship.

In UserController:

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    return view('users.show', compact('user'));
}
```

**users/show.blade.php:**

```
Posts: @include('users.show.tasks', ['tasks'=>$user->tasks()]);
```

**users/show/tasks.blade.php:**

`Active Tasks Count: {{$tasks->active()->count()}}`

Query:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `tasks` inner join `user_task` on `tasks`.`id` = `user_task`.`task_id` where `user_task`.`user_id` = '1' and `status` = '4';
```

`Pending Posts Count: {{$posts->pending()->count()}}`

Query:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `tasks` inner join `user_task` on `tasks`.`id` = `user_task`.`task_id` where `user_task`.`user_id` = '1' and `status` = '4' and `status` = '3';
```

This Is Tasks Method In User Model

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class)->latest();
}
```

Scopes In Task Model

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', 4);
}

public function scopePending($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', 3);
}
```

When I check the query using `laravel-debugbar`, for the second query the result includes two status ids, instead of one

Comment: Please include your models. What is `posts` and its relationship to the `User` and `Task` models?

Comment: models models models )))

Comment: Models Are OK , the problem is Active Scope remain when I want to change to another scope

Comment: Your question is pointless if you don't post the code of your models. Downvoting.

Comment: I just added task method from user model

Comment: where do `active()` and `pending()` methods come from?

Comment: I added local scopes

Comment: so what? I added the models

Comment: How about `$posts->pending()->tasks()` or it's just a typo?

Comment: are you kidding me?

Comment: Nope :) You send `tasks` to the view `$user->tasks()`, however you don't show what `$posts` is.